# Asp pattern page execution

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on an old asp project. I am new in project. My question is,

I required to execute the certain number of pages in a specific time but when I put in a loop to execute the page for certain pattern it execute only one pattern and shows time out expired problem. Though I searched in net what ever answer I get it will not fulfill my requirement. So my team lead said we have to find out some thing that can execute my page for 3 min each then it call back freshly. Is there any method is there in asp. as I am new in asp. as it possible or share some idea.

I want to execute for each pattern. Here is my simple code.

```vb
dim arrList()
dim mySQL,x,strPtrn

mySQL=""
x=0
strPtrn=""
mySQL="select distinct(pattern_no) from pattern_master where std between (dateadd(hh,8,getdate())) and (dateadd(hh,11,getdate()))" 

set rstptrnmst= conn.Execute(mySQL)

do until rstptrnmst.EOF
    for each ptrn in rstptrnmst.Fields
      ' Response.Write(x.name)
       'Response.Write(" = ")
       'Response.Write(x.value & "<br />")        
        ReDim Preserve arrList(x)
        arrList(x)=ptrn.value  
       x=x+1
    next
    Response.Write("<br />")
    rstptrnmst.MoveNext    
loop
rstptrnmst.close
conn.close

'for each ptrn in arrList
'response.Write("<br>" & ptrn)
'next

for each ptrn in arrList
Session("pattern")=ptrn
server.Execute("processFNO.asp")
Session("pattern")=""
response.write("The first pattern " & ptrn & "<br />")
next


'Response.Redirect("processFNO.asp?fno="&arrList(0)) 
 %>
```

So I want execute that page for each pattern. How can I? For each pattern it take 3 min(approx).any idea?

thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is going to take that long to run you will need to set the script timeout option to cater for that:

```
<%
Server.ScriptTimeout = 180
%>
```

The timeout is set in seconds, with the default being 90. You should set this at the very top of your page.

More information about timeouts here: [How do I increase timeout values](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-increase-timeout-values.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply rainey. i already set the timeout values 180 seconds but it still not working for me. is any idea? the sample code which is seen by you is not mentioned the server.scriptTimeout property.so plz give any idea.

Comment: Try setting it much longer, say 1800, and seeing if it completes. Also try setting some simple debug code in there marking timing of each section so you can see where the bottleneck actually is.

Comment: Thanks Rainey for constantly replying. i am just try this one than get back to you.

Comment: My system.time out error is solved. but look at that code which is generate flightplan for each pattern.for each ptrn in arrList
Session("pattern")=ptrn
server.Execute("processFNO.asp")
Session("pattern")=""
response.write("The first pattern " & ptrn & "<br />")
next  in here the processFno.asp page execute for first pattern but it does not execute for second pattern. some where else it stop the execution. how can i find where it stop. why it is not executed for second pattern. can u help me plz. if you tell i can send the processFNo.asp page also.

Comment: iam clear that error also. thanks Rainey for helping. Each time the pattern is working and execute it properly. i just miss one file to include. any way thanks a lot.